# removeAllRanges() method is not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, html

hi there the idea is to copy the selected nodes and there text then remove the selection but i dont know why it's not working:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        var ancestor = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
        var child = ancestor.childNodes;
        var len = child.length, div=[], text = [];

        for (var i =0; i<len; i++){
            div.push(child[i].localName);
            text.push(child[i].textContent);
        }
        sel.removeAllRanges();
```